# What lint configuration to use to eliminate the warning : Invalid JSDoc tag name

Tags: javascript, node.js, documentation, eslint

I am using eslint to set up my node js project but I keep getting the following warnings:

[image]

Now in my .eslint.json I am unable to find a rule/technique to help ignore these new tags and types. I have looked in the following documentation:
https://eslint.org/docs/rules/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that you are also using https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-jsdoc

If so then you have to add this rule to your eslint config file:

```
"jsdoc/check-tag-names": ["error", { "definedTags": ["consumes", "produces", "route"] }],
```

and whatever custom tags you also have in your docs...